# Find References not working in Eclipse Maven projects of different versions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, m2eclipse

We have a number of different Java Maven projects, each with different versions and each using one or more of the other Maven projects. They are all imported into Eclipse as Maven java projects, with (Maven) Workspace Resolution enabled and 'everything' is dandy except for the Find References functionality which doesn't work when a Maven project version is updated. 
Scenarios is as follows:

Sample setup:
Initial Project A  pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.deepak.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>a-project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

Class in Project A

```
public ClassA {
  public static void someMethodA() {
  }
}
```

Project B pom.xml what uses Project A as a dependency:
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.deepak.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>b-project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.deepak.test</groupId>
           <artifactId>a-project</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Class in project B that uses Class A (import omitted) from Project A

```
public ClassB {
  public static void someMethodB() {
       ClassA.someMethodA();
  }
}
```

With this setup, in project A if I right click on *someMethodA()*  class *ClassA* and select *References -> Workspace*, Eclipse correctly shows **ClassB.someMethodB()** the Search View.

However IF I update project A's version tag to say the release version, i.e. change version tag in Project A pom.xml to:

```
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

And *then* if we perform the *Find References* action again, Eclipse  will **NOT** show *ClassB.someMethodB()* as a reference. Is there any way we can make Eclipse show this as a potential match (with an older version of the jar perhaps)?

I know that doing a File Search is the only other solution, but that is not as accurate as doing a reference match from class files, and results in duplicate matches with Maven sub-modules etc.

I am using Eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars), with JDK 1.8 and Maven 3.3 if that helps

Comment: I am not sure this is a good idea. If you are referencing 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, why should it show 1.0.0? This is not the version you compile against.

Comment: @JFMeier Yes, strictly speaking, since the Project A version has changed to 1.0.0 and Project B is referring to Project A's 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT revision, reference for Project A class need not be displayed. However Eclipse has a 'potential match' functionality when it looks at application libraries etc for other searches, so in this case, it would be helpful if this reference was shown as a potential match. There are many times, where we bump up versions of projects but still need to know where a particular function is being called from dependant projects, even if they are referring older versions